# How can I do subquery inside FROM SQL in node sequalize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

How can I do subquery inside FROM SQL in node sequalize.js
I am using node sequalize.js and postgres SQL.
Eg:

```
SELECT
   name,
   string_agg(date_start::text,' / ') as date_start,
   string_agg(date_end::text,' / ') as date_end,
   string_agg(sem_range::text,' / ') as sem_range

FROM(

SELECT
name,
sem,
date_start,
days,
date_end
[sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN sem = 'S1' THEN date_start - days ELSE NULL END"), 'sem_start'],
[sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN sem = 'S1' THEN date_end - days ELSE NULL END"), 'sem_end'],
[sequelize.literal("CASE WHEN sem = 'S1' THEN to_char(date_start - days,'YYYY/MM/DD') || ' - ' || to_char(date_end - days,'YYYY/MM/DD') ELSE NULL END"), 'sem_range']

FROM semester as semester

GROUP BY sem, date_start, date_end, days) temp

GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sub query then there is no direct way but you can go throw this link. [Is it possible to do a subquery with Sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157687/is-it-possible-to-do-a-subquery-with-sequelize-js)
Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you. but I need to do it without include, from same table. for removing some column in group by.